# How would I use right click on a single click mouse

Tags: raspbian-wheezy, mouse

[Return to the FAQ](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/6653/6609)

---

I have a [single click apple mouse](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000ACOBI) which I am using to control my Raspberry Pi. I am using the recommended [Raspbian "Wheezy"](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads).

*Is there a way for me to make it so that `ctrl-click` is right click?*

Comment: `Apple meece` are not compatible with real world applications- They are nice but are fiddly with any other OS other than iOS. Buy a 2+ button mouse for a few bucks? `ctrl+click` again- only used in iOS- never seen that in any other OS I ever used

Comment: +1 for 'just buy yourself a 2+ button mouse', better than doing all kinds of hacks 'n' tools to control it with a 1 button mouse.

Comment: @ppumkin Actually, my current Apple mouse has full double click support (I use the [mighty mouse](http://compare.ebay.com/like/370635103783?var=lv&ltyp=AllFixedPriceItemTypes&var=sbar) on my mac, have yet to upgrade to [magic mouse](http://www.apple.com/magicmouse/)) The reason why I am having issues with my current mouse is because it is from the days of power-pc, *single-click* apple mice. Lastly, iOS is for iPhones, iPads, and iPod Touches; Mac OSX is the OS run on iMacs.

Comment: Mighty mouse . drool +1

Comment: I disagree about buying a new mouse. This is a Raspberry Pi people, it's meant for hacking. Coming up with your own solution. I control mine using my Windows Phone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I dont have a Apple Mouse, but this [mouseemu](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/mouseemu) should work.

> - emulate middle and right click
> - emulate mouse wheel
> - block trackpad while typing

First, update your firmware and software.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now, install `mouseemu` by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install mouseemu
```

You might also need to restart (you could also just restart services, but the RPi reboot's quickly enough).

**How to Use MouseEmu**

```
mouseemu’s default configuration file is stored in /etc/default/mouseemu
```

Open the file by typing the following command in a terminal window.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/mouseemu
```

Look for the following line, this line will make the middle click work while holding down the left Apple (also known as splat) key.

```
#MID_CLICK=”-middle 125 272″ # Left Apple Key (LEFTMETA) + click
```

The following line will enable the right click while holding down Left ctrl

```
#RIGHT_CLICK=”-right 29 272″ # Left Ctrl + click
```

Uncomment the previous two lines by removing the `#` in the beginning of the line. Now save the file `ctrl + x` (follow the instructions for saving, should be the `y` key and then `enter` key).

Then either restart your Raspberry Pi or try restarting the `mouseemu` service by typing the following. **NOTE** I'm not 100% sure of the syntax here.

Retart service

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mouseemu restart
```

Restart Raspberry Pi

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: So... exactly how do I use this?

Comment: I've edited my answer with instructions. Tell me if you come right.

Comment: wow - a real demand for mac meece users out there. lol +1

Comment: @VincetP Thank you so much - this is an awesome answer. I am going to edit it to include updated firmware and software - it didn't work until I did that

Answer (score 1):

you can directly map any spare key to any mouse button:

http://promberger.info/linux/2008/06/03/binding-a-key-to-the-middle-mouse-button-with-xmodmap-and-xkbset/